# "State" undefined when trying to map fetched json data into React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm fetching data from a wordpress api. I see the array of data when I log to console. On mapping the data, I get an error saying "#myStateName.map is not a function".

I've gone on ReactJS.org, CSS Tricks and even Stack overflow to find solutions but nothing seems to work

```
class WPHome extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  details: []
};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
fetch(API_URL)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result['0'])
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        details: [result]
      });
    },
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    }

  )
}

render() {
const { error, isLoaded, details } = this.state;
if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
  return (
    <div>
      {details.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.id}</p>
          <div>
            <img src={item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url} alt={item.id} />
          </div>
          <p>{item.content}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
  }
```

I expect that my data is passing into the HTML block but I get thrown an [error](http://prntscr.com/oviqt4).

Comment: can you share the response of API

Comment: `Object { id: 2, date: "2019-08-05T11:51:22", date_gmt: "2019-08-05T11:51:22", guid: {…}, modified: "2019-08-05T12:51:42", modified_gmt: "2019-08-05T12:51:42", slug: "home", status: "publish", type: "page", … }
WPHome.jsx:21
`

Comment: the response result you are getting is an array or object please console.log(typeof result)

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of your browser console by 
```console.table(result) ```

Comment: It says "Object" `console.log(typeof result)`

Comment: You can't use .map on an object. It can only be used on arrays.

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/ovjft6)

Comment: use Object.keys() or entries if you are iterating over object

Comment: Can you illustrate how? or possibly convert the object to an array? @TapanDave

Comment: It doesn't show any data. So  `<p>{item.id}</p>` shows an empty `<p></p>`

Comment: Are you requesting for a single post or a collection (list of posts)? Show the `API_URL` please. Try to set: `details: Object.values(result)` if you are requesting for a list of posts and your response is an object.

Comment: `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?_embed&filter[orderby]=date&order=asc`
I want to use data from a particular post not a list of post.

Comment: @EdwardBella i have share  an fiddle please refer below answer

Comment: So you have to set `details` to `result` and use it in `render()` without `.map`, just `details.id`, `details.content` etc.

Comment: @pako Using it without mapping still doesn't show any data. [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ovlin2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Had to use Axios though but it worked.

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  details: []
};
}

componentDidMount(){
axios
  .get(API_URL)
  .then(response => response.data.map(detail => ({
    image: `${detail._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url}`,
      content: `${detail.content.rendered}`,
      id: `${detail.id}`
    }))
  )
  .then(details => {
    this.setState({
      details,
      isLoading: false
    });
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}


render() {
const { isLoading, details } = this.state;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
      {!isLoading ? (
        details.map(detail => {
          const { id, content, image } = detail;
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <p>{content}</p>
              <div>
                <img src={image} alt={id} />
              </div>
              <p>{content}</p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
          <p>Loading</p>
      )
      }
  </React.Fragment>
)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize `details` in your state. Add it here:

```
this.state = {
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  result: [],
  details: [] // <- missing initialization
};
```

Comment: So try to comment out the code in `componentDidMount()` and check if the error will raise. If not the problem is inside `result['0']` - try to check if you are setting a good key of this response. You can also add `console.log(typeof details, details)` inside your render to show what kind of data you have there.

Comment: On commenting out, the error disappears. If I `console.log(result['0])`, I see all the data contained within that set. So I'm not sure its the problem, could it?

Comment: it says undefined for `console.log(typeof details)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your state declaration in the constructor add the following

```
 this.state = {
  details:[],
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  result: []
 }
```

The error might be caused due to this.state.details being undefined at the start.

I've also noticed that on your fetch request you are doing the following.

```
  this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    details: result['0']
  });
```

Since result is an array shouldn't it be set to details state as follows.

```
  this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    details: result
  });
```

Comment: Yes. My API returns 2 array data set but I want to dive into the first one hence the "['0']".

I've also defined the details state but the "details.map is not a function" error is still being thrown.

Comment: At the line `details: [result]`, you still need to use either the spread operator `[...result]`, or just the first element `[result[0]]`, or else you'll get a nested array

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you did not declare `details` variable in your state.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try to run:

```
render (
   <div>
          {
            details.map(item => (
             <div key={item.id}>
              <p>{item.status}</p>
             </div>
         }
   </div>
);
```

And post how that goes?

Comment: It doesn't run. it doessn't recognize "details".

Comment: `this.state.details`

Comment: The .map function is only available on an array.
It looks like result isn't in the format you are expecting it to be (it is {} but you are expecting []). Or, you can use something like this: details = Array.from(props.data); or similar... Try this and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

please use the below setState statement as your result is an object

```
this.setState({ isLoaded: true, details: [result] });
```

Comment: It is not seeing any data from the state. If i map `<p>{item.id}</p>`, it shows an empty `<p></p>` on render.

Answer (score 0):

to iterate over object please refer below link - https://jsfiddle.net/oek6um0h/1/

```
{Object.keys(details).length && Object.keys(details).map((item,k) => {
return <any></any>
}) || <p>nothing found</p>}
```

map is for array not for object to use map we need to use `Object.keys()` which method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop

Comment: The fiddle doesn't display any result.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `details` in the `constructor` with default value instead of `result`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        details: [] // define missing
    };
}
```